# ImagickException: Unable to read image from the filehandle in Imagick->readimagefile()

Tags: php, window, imagick, windows-server-2012, iis-8

I'm trying to read a pdf but i got this error

**ImagickException**: Unable to read image from the filehandle in `Imagick->readimagefile()`
and the line where the error is when readImageFile is called.

```
$handle = fopen($fileUrl, 'rb');
$img = new Imagick();
$img->readImageFile($handle);
```

This code was working perfectly on apache linux, but I had to migrate to IIS and I have install imagick 3.1.0RC2 with the soft ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2012-06-27 Q16 (x86).
I also have a x86 PHP 5.4.22 non thread and I'm using IIS 8 on a windows server 2012. The php_imagick.dll is for 5.14 nts so it should work.

When I try to install Imagick 6.8.7 for obvious reason it doesn't work at all.

Any ideas ?

Cheers

Comment: What is your $fileUrl content?

Comment: $fileUrl is file_create_url($file->uri); but I don't think that the problem

Comment: What version of linux? CentOS? Ubuntu?

Comment: IIS 8 on a Windows Server 2012 :(

Comment: I'm having this problem too, anyone know a solution or cause for this?

Comment: I fixed it!   The problem was a permission problem.. but to which directory I didn't know.. answer: C:\Windows\Temp.  It figures out, that ImageMagick tries to write the output to that directory under files that are named "magick-XXXXXXX".   These files are the outputs of every individual call to convert.exe.   when PHP tries accessing them, it doesnt have a permissions to that directory, so it fails.   Try to check if that answers your problem and let me know.

Comment: It was 2 years ago so I'm not sure but I think that was the answer